# Pipe Data From Command Line into C# Console App

Tags: c#, console

I have a basic C# Console app that looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  if (args.Length > 0)
  {
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("arg: " + arg);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("No args received from standard output.");
  }
}
```

My app will eventually receive data from a third-party app that will pipe data to this console app. In an effort to test this scenario, I tried running the following:

```
echo "hello world" | MyConsoleApp.exe
```

When I ran it, I saw `No args received from standard output.`. However, I was expecting to see `hello world`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piped outputs from another command are not passed to your application as command line arguments (i.e. `args[]` in `Main()`). Rather, they need to be read in by your application from the standard input (`stdin`). You need to use `Console.Read()` or `Console.ReadLine()` for that.

Comment: Can you clarify this more? How can I `Console.Read()` for previous output?